# pass string array values as return type string when condition is met

Tags: c#, arrays, string, function, return-type

I've a module which returns string array "string[]". It contains success code and author name.

```
var get_author = SetBookInfo(Id, Name);
```

this function *SetBookInfo* returns response code and author name. 
my condition is ::

> if response code is "sucess" return author name "william".  ["success", "william"]
>
> if response code is "failed" return "failed"

```
public string GetAuthorName()
{
    var get_author = SetBookInfo(Id, Name); // returns string[]

    if (get_author != null && get_author.Length > 0)
        {
        // how to write the above logic
        }

    else
        return "problem in accessing the function";
}
```

How can I do this? Please verify if my approach is correct or not.Is there any other way? Please help.

Comment: Code seems to be correct. What is the issue here exactly ?

Comment: What is index of Response Code ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad Response Code index is 0

Comment: @HarveySpecter I can not proceed further how to code the logic. please guide

Comment: And you want to return string array or comma separated string.

Comment: @MairajAhmad I want to return string. Suppose response code is "success" return author name "william". Is not the question clear???

Comment: Do you want to return a single author or probably two or more author in some cases?

Comment: @Searock no single author in every case

Comment: @user4221591 You don't need to pass status in your array or collections just check if it is null incase if you don't have any authors and pass null incase if there are no authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public string GetAuthorName()
{
string []get_author = SetBookInfo(Id, Name); // returns string[]
if (get_author != null && get_author.Length > 0)
 {
   if(get_author[0].ToLower().Equals("success"))
      return get_author[1];
   else
     return "failed";
  }
else
    return "problem in accessing the function";
}
```

And if you want to return multiple string than you can return `List of strings`.

```
public List<string> GetAuthorName()
{
string []get_author = SetBookInfo(Id, Name); // returns string[]
List<string> list=new List<string>();
if (get_author != null && get_author.Length > 0)
 {
   if(get_author[0].ToLower().Equals("success"))
    {
     list.Add("success"); 
     list.Add(get_author[1]);
    }
   else
     list.Add("failed");
  }
else
    list.Add("problem in accessing the function");
 return list;
}
```

Comment: the method's return type is `string`, not `List<string>`

Comment: @Shaharyar yes but please look at what should be returned when response is success user wants to return multiple strings.

Comment: No, he just wants to return the name of `Author`. I think you slightly mistook the requirement

Comment: @MairajAhmad thank you very much for reply. Can you please share you previous reply. returning list type. that will be helpful for me in other cases.

Comment: OK i am adding it as an Edit,

Comment: @MairajAhmad let me verify.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
public string GetAuthorName()
{
    var get_author = SetBookInfo(Id, Name); // returns string[]

    if (get_author != null && get_author.Length > 0)
        {
            if(get_author[0] == "success") return get_author[1]; //e.g. ["success", "william"], "william" will be returned
            else if (get_author[0] == "failed") return "failed";
        }

    else
        return "problem in accessing the function";
}
```

providing that index of response code is 0 and that of author is 1.